# How to replace content element in an Array Controller

Tags: arrays, ember.js, controller

Currently working on part of the app that requires cloning an element from the content, then modifying cloned element and saving back to model. I am having a problem when saving the cloned element and having to replace the old item with cloned one. What I am currently doing is changing all the properties of the old item like so (it works):

```
Blocks.replace = function(item1, item2) {
  for(var k in item2) {
    Ember.set(item1, k, item2[k]);
  }
};

var selectedEmployment = this.get("controllers.employmentDataEntry").get("selectedEmployment");
var modelItem = content.findBy("@id", selectedEmployment["@id"]);
Blocks.replace(modelItem, selectedEmployment);
```

I'm trying to use the ArrayController replaceContent method, but I get an error saying "Invalid array length" when trying to run the following code:

```
var employmentIndex = content.indexOf(modelItem);
this.replaceContent(employmentIndex, 0, selectedEmployment);
```

Am I doing this incorrectly? Is there a better way of replacing an item?
Note: I am using JSON as a model. The ArrayController that is used when calling replaceContent contains an array of length 2.

Comment: lolz, issue was I need to pass in an array for the third varaible in replaceContent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix: Need to send in an array to replaceContent method. So change selectedEmployment to [SelectedEmployment]. Also, change 0 to 1, otherwise, content will end up having both element and cloned element.

```
this.replaceContent(employmentIndex, 1, [selectedEmployment]);
```

Comment: I assume the second param should be `this.content.length`, no?

Comment: Yes. It's the number of items you want to remove from content. http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html#method_replaceContent